# Vue i18n dynamic translation in JS file

Tags: javascript, vue-i18n

I have JS file:

```
const menu = {
    name: i18n.t('Strona główna'),
}
```

and translation in `en.yml` file:

```
"Strona główna": "Home page"
```

I have too file with config i18n:

```
export const i18n = new VueI18n({
    locale: language,
    fallbackLocale: language,
    silentTranslationWarn: true,
    messages: loadLocaleMessages(),
})
```

When I change `locale` and `fallbackLocale` to 'en' and refresh page then translation work correctly. But  when I trying change language using button (dynamic translation) then translation not working.

**How I can fix dynamic translation in JS file?**